# whiptail info box use

Tags: linux, whiptail

Could you please tell me what is the use of Whiptail info box. [Whiptail Info Box](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail)

The message just comes and goes. Is there a way to display the message for a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the *[manual page](http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/manuals/man/whiptail.html)*:

> **`--infobox`** *text height width*
>   
> An **info** box is basically a **message** box. However, in this case, **whiptail** will exit immediately after displaying the message to the user. The screen is not cleared when **whiptail** exits, so that the message will remain on the screen until the calling shell script clears it later. This is useful when you want to inform the user that some operations are carrying on that may require some time to finish.

However, if you are running in an xterm, its terminal description may use the [alternate screen](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) for full-screen applications such as whiptail. In that case, the screen would be cleared immediately after displaying the message.  [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html) attempts to work around this case, to keep the message displayed (see the description of `--keep-tite` in its [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Common-Options)).